# Java Swing Event Bubbling/Capturing

Tags: java, swing

Does Java have concepts similar to pubsub or data binding?

I am learning Java GUI (Swing in particular).  I have a few forms which I want to keep in sync by sharing events and singleton object between them.  In the other languages I know, this is handled either by data binding or by event synchronization/triggering.

I've seen that you can do events like `source.getParent().doSomething()`, but coming from web development, the idea of tracking parental references just seems absolutely crazy to me.  I'll always be able to trace back to the parent I suppose, but this just feels wrong.

Is this just how Java does things?  Is there any way to affect items regardless of where they are in the application?

I've had no luck turning up anything about a more web-like way of doing things such as bubbling and capturing phases of an event lifecycle.  Maybe my approach of keeping many forms/views open at once is too weird for the way Java works...  i could just close/open forms and the initialization would grab the updated values.

Regardless of whether or not my design is good, I'm just trying to learn Java so even if this specific example isn't applicable, I'd still like to know how to affect items from afar without component A having to know that component B is listening.

In psuedocode since I don't know the Java way to express this, I'm hoping to be able to do:

### **Without data binding**

**Foo Component:**

```
private void initialize() {

   this.addEventListener(CONSTANTS.NAME_OF_EVENT, this.doSomething);  // waits for somebody to tell us to update
}


private void doSomething() {
   this.value = singleton.getInstance().value; // gets "123" from Bar's dispatch
   ...
}
```

And in **Bar Component**, I'd hope to be able to do:

```
private void triggerSomething() {
   this.singleton.getInstance.setValue(123);  // updates the singleton
   this.dispatchEvent(CONSTANTS.NAME_OF_EVENT); // tells anybody who cares about NAME_OF_EVENT to do something about it (ideally, the singleton would do the dispatching but for clarity I separated them)
}
```

### **With data binding**

**Foo Component:**

```
private void initialize() {
    this.singleton.getInstance().setValue(123);
}
```

And in **Bar Component**, I'd hope that txtValue.setText() magically happens by virtue of being bound to the singleton value.

```
private void initialize() {
   txtValue.setText(this.singleton.getInstance().getValue());
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. There are a number of bindings APIs or even "event bus". Oddly enough, a better solution would be to investigate MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to think in terms of a [Property Change Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html), instead of an Event listener.  Events would be at a lower level than you want (button press, button release, key press, key release).  A property change is higher level: "this property changed from this value to that value."

```
public class PropertyChangeBean {
    protected PropertyChangeEvent pce(String name, Object from, Object to) {
        return new PropertyChangeEvent(this, name, from, to);
    }

    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs;

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        if (pcs == null)
            pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        if (pcs != null)
            pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    protected void fireChange(String property, Object from, Object to) {
        if (pcs != null && !Objects.equals(from, to))
            pcs.firePropertyChange(pce(property, from, to));
    }

    protected void fireChange(String property, int from, int to) {
        if (pcs != null && from != to)
            pcs.firePropertyChange(pce(property, from, to));
    }

    protected void fireChange(String property, boolean from, boolean to) {
        if (pcs != null && from != to)
            pcs.firePropertyChange(pce(property, from, to));
    }

    protected void fireChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
        if (pcs != null)
            pcs.firePropertyChange(pce);
    }
}
```

And create your "Bar" bean like:

```
public class Bar extends PropertyChangeBean {

    private int value = 0;

    public void setValue(int new_value) {
        fireChange("value", value, value = new_value);
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And "Foo" would register as PropertyChangeListener on "Bar"

```
class Foo {
    Foo() {
        bar.addPropertyChangeListener(e -> {
             // Fetch and use new value of bar
        });
    }
}
```

You can even use the [Vetoable Change Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/VetoableChangeListener.html) to have listeners which can respond "no, that isn't an acceptable value" when a change is attempted.